# bind absolute images to longlistselector in mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have downloaded a set of items from a web site and got text details into a binding class. In these i have image uri which i need to bind to the longlist selector along with other details. The problem is that I am not able to download, indeed there has been an exception in design view when i place a image converter itself.

Converter code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var imageFile = value as string;

        if (imageFile != null)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
            image.UriSource = new Uri("http://www.somewebsite.com/" + imageFile, UriKind.Absolute);

            return image;
        }
        else
            return null;

    }
```

LLS:

```
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="500" Margin="0,0,0,12">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <local:ImageConverter x:Name="imageConverter"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="{Binding Path=ImgSrc, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}"/>
                        </Grid.Background>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to download it yourself. Just bind to the path string.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Height="500" Margin="0,0,0,12">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="{Binding ImgSrc}"/>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Here the Imgsrc is something like http://www.stockphotos.com/one.png. So the absolute images have to be downloaded unlike the photos in the xap file itself right?

Comment: @max no, I don't think so. I tried with an absolute http URI and it worked perfectly.